# Strapi controller throwing a NotFoundError : I get a response status 500 instead 404... How can I fix it?

Tags: strapi

I have a Strapi controller method that fires a NotFoundError:

```
  async matchTrack(ctx) {
    throw new NotFoundError('YO NOT FOUND');
  }
```

When I call the endpoint, the error is thrown, but **the response code is 500 instead of 404**.

> [2023-06-08 16:05:39.333] error: YO NOT FOUND NotFoundError: YO NOT FOUND
> at Object.matchTrack

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by @darwin-facsts answer, here's how to handle this.
List of context error methods [here](https://github.com/jshttp/http-errors#list-of-all-constructors) (should be lower camel-case)

```
//controller method
async matchTrack(ctx){
  const body = ctx.request.body;

  try{
    //...service method...
  } catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof NotFoundError) {
      return ctx.notFound(error.message,error.details)
    }
    throw(error);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this `return ctx.badRequest('YO NOT FOUND');`